# When does the Android FusedLocationApi update location using PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY

Tags: android, gps, location

I have setup Google's Fused Location API for my Android app and am able to receive location updates (gps coords every minute due to my update interval set to 60000) when setting the priority to PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, but have been unsuccessful when using "PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY"

My question is the following: 
When/How does PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY actually give updated locations? 
Apparently it's not using gps at all, so does  onLocationChanged() get called when hopping to different wifi networks/cell towers?

I ask because I need a way of testing this and not sure if an emulator can do this. I have a physical android phone but it only has wifi.

**TLDR onLocationChanged() gets called when using  PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY based on (setInterval()/setFastestInterval or setSmallestDisplacement()), but when does onLocationChanged() get called when using PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY?**

I greatly appreciate the help, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When/How does `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` actually give updated
>   locations? Apparently, it's not using GPS at all, so does
>   onLocationChanged() get called when hopping to different wifi
>   networks/cell towers?

**Answer:**  a low power impact. These applications should consider [PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest#PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY) combined with a faster `setFastestInterval(long)` (such as 1 minute) and a slower `setInterval(long)` (such as 60 minutes). They will only be assigned power blame for the interval set by `setInterval(long)`, but can still receive locations triggered by other applications at a rate up to `setFastestInterval(long)`. This style of a request is appropriate for many location-aware applications, including background usage. Do be careful to also throttle `setFastestInterval(long)` if you perform heavy-weight work after receiving an update - such as using the network.

> but when does `onLocationChanged()` get called when using
>   `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY`?

**Answer:** `onLocationChanged()`  will invoke while location change base on your `setInterval() & setFastestInterval().`

**Edit :**

Difference between type [PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest#PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY) & [PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest#PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)

Use with a priority constant such as PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY. No other values are accepted.

The priority of the request is a strong hint to the LocationClient for which location sources to use. For example, PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY is more likely to use GPS, and PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY is more likely to use WIFI & Cell tower positioning, but it also depends on many other factors (such as which sources are available) and is implementation dependent.

> I need a way of testing this and not sure if an emulator can do this.

**Answer:** You can test this scenario in the emulator using send fake location.

Comment: Thank you Chintan for the response!

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that set onLocationChanged() should be invoked purely based on setInterval() & setFastestInterval() despite which setPriority() I use? (aka PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY or PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)

Comment: If my above comment is true, then PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY and PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY are purely for how accuracy and have nothing to do with how often onLocationChanged() is called. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. But if I want to display realtime speed, will PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY be able to provide that with a decent accuracy?